# Quickest goal scored in each World Cup edition

Tags: football, statistics, records, world-cup

I'm looking for the following statistic, if available:

> Quickest goal scored in any match throughout the tournament in each edition of the World Cup.

For example, for the 2014 World Cup, Clint Dempsey scored the fastest tournament goal at 30 seconds in the USA's group stage match against Ghana.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info) post with a partial answer. If you have can add some missing information or additional sources, go ahead and edit this post.

The statistics below should be taken with caution. They are only as reliable as the sources where they were taken from. Moreover, it's not sure whether we can rely on such exact timekeeping - especially for old events.

- [2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics): [Mathias Jørgensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathias_J%C3%B8rgensen) (0:57)
- [2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics): [Clint Dempsey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clint_Dempsey) (0:30)
- [2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics): [Thomas Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_M%C3%BCller) (2:38)
- [2006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics): [Asamoah Gyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asamoah_Gyan) (1:08)
- [2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_FIFA_World_Cup_statistics): [Hakan Sükür](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakan_%C5%9E%C3%BCk%C3%BCr) (0:11)
- [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_FIFA_World_Cup): [Celso Ayala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celso_Ayala) (0:53)
- [1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup): [Gabriel Batistuta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Batistuta) (2nd minute)
- [1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_FIFA_World_Cup): [Safet Sušić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safet_Su%C5%A1i%C4%87) (5th minute)
- [1986](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_FIFA_World_Cup): [Emilio Butragueño](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emilio_Butrague%C3%B1o) (1:03)
- [1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_FIFA_World_Cup): [Bryan Robson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_Robson) (0:27)
- [1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_FIFA_World_Cup): [Bernard Lacombe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Lacombe) (0:37)
- [1974](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1974_FIFA_World_Cup): [Johan Neeskens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Neeskens) (1:20)<sup>1</sup>
- [1970](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1970_FIFA_World_Cup): [Ladislav Petráš](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladislav_Petr%C3%A1%C5%A1)
- [1966](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1966_FIFA_World_Cup): [Pak Seung-zin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pak_Seung-zin) (0:50)
- [1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_FIFA_World_Cup): [Václav Mašek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A1clav_Ma%C5%A1ek) (0:16)
- [1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_FIFA_World_Cup): [Vavá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vav%C3%A1) (2nd minute)
- [1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_FIFA_World_Cup): [Suat Mamat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suat_Mamat)
- [1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_FIFA_World_Cup): [Alfredo dos Santos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfredo_dos_Santos)
- [1938](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1938_FIFA_World_Cup): [Émile Veinante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Veinante), [Arne Nyberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arne_Nyberg) (both 0:35)
- [1934](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1934_FIFA_World_Cup): [Ernst Lehner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Lehner) (0:25)
- [1930](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1930_FIFA_World_Cup): [Adalbert Desu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adalbert_De%C8%99u) (0:50)

<sup>1</sup>This is also the fastest goal in the history of world cup *finals*.

Sources:

- Pages with individual stats for World Cup tournaments [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:FIFA_World_Cup_statistics).
- Wikipedia: [Fastest goals in association football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastest_goals_in_association_football)
- [Top 10 – The fastest goals in the World Cup history](http://www.footballgate.com/2014/06/17/top-10-the-fastest-goals-in-the-world-cup-history/)
- [The 12 Fastest Goals Scored In World Cup History](https://www.ranker.com/list/fastest-goals-scored-in-world-cup-history/ranker-soccer)
- [Fastest World Cup goals](https://www.eurosport.com/football/fastest-world-cup-goals_sto4290957/story.shtml)
- The World Cup, A Very Peculiar History by David Arscott - [Fastest World Cup goals](https://books.google.com/books?id=c-a7BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT26)
- [FIFA World Cup superlatives](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/fifafacts/mcwc/ip-301_04a_super_57313.pdf) at FIFA website ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170922050813/http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/fifafacts/mcwc/ip-301_04a_super_57313.pdf))
- [First-round facts and figures at the World Cup: Leading scorers...](https://www.upi.com/Archives/1986/06/14/First-round-facts-and-figures-at-the-World-CupLeading-scorers/5987519105600/)
- Mis mundiales by Juan María Alfaro, [Page 68](https://books.google.sk/books?id=WVgdc0x5sOgC&pg=PA68) - Los Goles Mas Rapidos De Cada Mundial
- [Denmark and Croatia set World Cup record for fastest goals](http://www.espn.com/soccer/fifa-world-cup/story/3553072/denmark-and-croatia-set-world-cup-record-for-fastest-goals)